# Negating a Spring Data JPA specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification` and implementing `toPredicate(…)` anonymously:

```
Someclass {
    public static Specification<SomeObject> getSth() {
         return Specifications.where(mainFilter()).and(secondFilter())
    }

    private static Specification<SomeObject> mainFilter() {
         // …
    }

    private static Specification<SomeObject> secondFilter() {
         return new Specification<SomeObject>() {
               @Override
               Predicate toPredicate(Root<ReportOrder> root,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                        JoinMap.
                        // … blah blah blah …

                    query.distinct();
               }
         }
    }
}
```

I have the problem with negating `secondFilter()`. If I just use `secondFilter()` against `repository.findAll(…)` I get exactly one element. I was hoping that if I use `Specifications.not(secondFilter())` I would get all but one, but I'm getting all instead.

Comment: It really depends on your query. Could you share it with us?

Comment: `Specifications.not` is the standard way. As commented by mneri, maybe it depends on the specific query which could have a loophole. Have you checked the SQL output via `org.hibernate.SQL` logger?